# Select the first 2 NA values of each row in a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

Given a dataframe like this:

```
           A         B         C         D         E
1         NA 0.1189026 0.1189026        NA        NA
2         NA 0.1189026 0.1189026        NA        NA
3         NA        NA        NA        NA        NA
4         NA        NA        NA        NA        NA
5  0.3214921        NA        NA 0.3214921 0.3214921
6         NA        NA        NA        NA        NA
7  0.3214921 0.1189026 0.1189026 0.3214921 0.3214921
8  0.3214921        NA        NA 0.3214921 0.3214921
9        NA 0.1189026 0.1189026        NA        NA
```

I would like to pick the first two non-NA values of each row. What should I do?

The return may look like this:

```
 [1,] 0.1189026 0.1189026
 [2,] 0.1189026 0.1189026
 [3,]        NA        NA
 [4,]        NA        NA
 [5,] 0.3214921 0.3214921
 [6,]        NA        NA
 [7,] 0.3214921 0.1189026
 [8,] 0.3214921 0.3214921
 [9,] 0.1189026 0.1189026
```

Comment: choose? You mean pick first two and put them in a new dataframe?  Can you give us a sample of the expected output?

Comment: Is the first column a real column or row names?

Comment: Try this, where `DF` is your data.frame `apply(DF,1,function(x) head(DF[!is.na(DF)],2) )`

Comment: @OdeToMyFiddle This does not work. You need to make `DF` inside function to `x`

Answer (score 1):

you can try this:

```
apply(df, 1, function(x) x[!is.na(x)][1:2])
```

or for transposed result:

```
t(apply(df, 1, function(x) x[!is.na(x)][1:2]))
```

Answer (score 1):

alternative:

```
library(magrittr)

DF %>% t %>% data.frame %>% lapply(function(x)head(x[!is.na(x)],2)) %>% do.call(rbind,.)
```

result:

```
#          [,1]      [,2]
# X2  0.1189026 0.1189026
# X3  0.1189026 0.1189026
# X6  0.3214921 0.3214921
# X8  0.3214921 0.1189026
# X9  0.3214921 0.3214921
# X10 0.1189026 0.1189026
```